# Accessing a specific control located in the footer template of a column using client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I need to access a label (lblTotalWeight) that is located in the footer template of a gridtemplatecolumn. From there I want to change the forecolor, though I want to do this all clientside. You can see in my function below that I have already accessed each row successfully, though it seems that doing so for the footer is not as straight forward. My research thus far keeps leading to server side solutions, or in once case a hardcoded row[] cell[] situation.

get_masterTableViewFooter has yet to return anything.

Oh my code behind is in C#.

JavaScript:

```
    function GridCreated(sender, eventArgs) {
        grid = $find("<%=rgActivities.ClientID %>");
        var masterTable = grid.get_masterTableView();
        var rows = masterTable.get_dataItems();
        var total = 0.0;

        for (var row = 0; row < rows.length; row++) {
            var rcb = rows[row].findControl("rcbWeight");
            total += parseInt(rcb.get_value());
        }

        if (total== 100) {
           //lblTotalWeight = black;
        } 
        else {
          //lblTotalWeight = Red;
        }
    }
```

(As a sidenote rcb is RadComboBox.)

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you set on doing this client-side? I don't see any reason that should be a requirement. I think it would actually make more sense to do this server-side.

Comment: I agree. The original functionality was a simple radnumeric text box column addition that did need to be client side. For whatever reason my brain  skipped and I decided I should get the initial column total client side, too. Now I figured it would be simple to just change the label color while I was here.

Comment: I still want to know how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to tweak it a bit, but something like this should get you close:

```
var footerLabelID = '<%= ((GridFooterItem)rgActivities.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.Footer)[0]).FindControl("lblTotalWeight").ClientID %>';

var footerLabel = document.getElementById(footerLabelID);
if (footerLabel){
    footerLabel.innerText = "Hello World!";
}
```